# What does ちょーなー mean?

Tags: hiragana

ファイナルがんばって！終わったらデートしてちょーなー

In that sentence.
Is the person saying date me or just simply, "go on date"?
And what does cho na mean?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This means:

```
Do your best in the final (match) ! After it finishes, please date with me."
```

I am a native Japanese speaker but I have never heard the expression ちょーなー.
So I thought it's from a dialect and googled ちょーなー but I found nothing.

This word might be a combination of `ちょー` and `なー`, I think.

`ちょー` is an abbreviation of `ちょうだい`, in a informal way.

Example:

```
デートしてちょー。 (Date with me.)
```

On the other hand, `なー` can be used in similar cases.

Example:

```
デートしてなー。 (Date with me.)
```

Sentences that ends with `なー` is mostly spoken by people who live in western Japan.

Comment: Hi, deto shite doesn't mean "date" in general? It means "Date me"? I was wondering if deto shite could refer to dating another person. THank you.

Comment: As you say, if `デートして` is literary translated in English, it just mean `date with someone`. But in most cases, `[私]{わたし}と (with me)` is hid before the beginning of `デートして`.
As a result, if a girl/boy say `デートして` to its boy/girlfriend, it means `Date with me`.
You won't ask your girl/boyfriend to "date with someone not me", will you? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I think there was some context before this sentence that made me confused. Cuz they may have discussed a date with someone else beforehand, and I am not sure if she means a date with THAT OTHER person or with her.

Comment: Since the speaker adds ちょーなー on the end (dialect for "please"), it's almost certainly "[with] me [the speaker]" -- unless the speaker and listener have some really unusual open relationship, *"Do your best in the final! Once you're done, please go on a date **with someone else**!"* sounds just super bizarre.  Though, I suppose the speaker *could* be saying that s/he expects the listener to do badly, and is therefore off-handedly breaking up with the listener... but probably not.

Answer (score 5):

I grew up saying and hearing 「ちょーな」 said by others on a daily basis.

This is an expression from Nagoya dialect and 「～～してちょう（な）」 means the same thing as 「～～してほしい = "I want you to ~~"」 in Standard Japanese.　The 「な」 is for emphasis and, therefore, is optional, and for extra emphasis, you can elongate the 「な」.

> Thus, 「[終]{お}わったらデートしてちょーなー。」 means "When you're finished, I want you to go out with me!"

OP should have provided more context so I could explain 「ファイナルがんばって！」.  If the speaker were talking to an idol, 「ファイナル」 would mean the final concert on a tour.  We do say 「ファイナル」 for that.

If, however, people shorten ファイナルファンタジー to ファイナル, then that might be what it refers to.  I do not play those games, so I am clueless on this.

Comment: I don't know how often it's used in Japanese, but it seems to me that it could also be ファイナル = 学期末試験 (final exam)

Comment: It is so in America, I know.  In Japan, I do not think I have ever heard it used to refer to a final exam.  Maybe at ICU or Sophia, they might, I dunno.

Comment: Hmm, there are a few sources ([here](http://nagoyaben.com/sagyou.html#area03), [here](http://hougen.u-biq.org/nagoya.html), and [here](http://www.unisys.co.jp/CHUBU/nagoyaben/njun/ta.html)) that says (し)てちょう is equivalent to (し)てください in standard Japanese.